# skip to the next word if the function is blocked at the current one or is taking too long

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want for my function to skip to the next word if the execution either doesn't work or take too long. Here's my function :

```
def encode(word):
      return bc.encode([[word]],is_tokenized=True)
```

I tried the try/exepct like this :

```
def bert(word):
        try:
            return bc.encode([[word]],is_tokenized=True)
        except:
         pass
```

But my code still stop running for some words. Is there a function that can say to my function to pass to the next word if it takes too long?

Comment: You can count the number of attempts and "give up" at one point if there were too many

Comment: If you want to skip, why did you put the `try/except` inside a `while True`? It will just try again and again with the same word...

Comment: I think you’re trying to solve the wrong problem here. **Why** is `bc.encode` stalling for some words? That’s probably a bug, right? I’d suggest debugging and fixing that. Maybe network issues?

Comment: @KonradRudolph It's a library that i'm only using. I can't change anything in it. At this point I just need the encode whatever word the library can give

Comment: @Tomerikoo I deleted the while true and it's still not working

Comment: @user93804 I’m aware, but the library function should still not stall if you’re running a local BERT server. If it does, something is wrong and setting a timeout wouldn’t really be appropriate. If you’re using an online service which uses rate limits or is otherwise congested, you can’t really control that, and in this case it might be appropriate to specify a timeout — [check the documentation](https://bert-as-service.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/client.html#module-client).

Comment: It would be helpful if you gave details about the library you're using (maybe it already offers a solution, as an answer points...)

Comment: @KonradRudolph I see what you mean, but honestly I don't know where the problem is. Right now i just need the vectors of the words that works. The timeout provided by the library does not solve the issue, as it returns null for every word that comes after the word where the issue is

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what `bc.encode` is, but I googled it and if it's `BertClient`, according to [this](https://bert-as-service.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/client.html) you can pass `timeout=x` to the constructor and I assume it will throw an exception if it takes more than that.

Comment: Hello thank you for your reply. When I use timeout=5000  it returns to me one encode per 5seconds, which is very long. I need encodes of 200.000 words and this will take forever

Comment: it's like the server shutdown after the word with the error and return Null to very word that comes after